# Using ajax with rails getting variable in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```
 View:
 / Modal products
 #productModal.modal.fade
  .modal-header
    %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "modal"} ×
     %h3 Add a product to your list
  .modal-body
 #product_step_1
   = form_for(@new_product, :url => products_path, :remote => true, :html =>            
   {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
    .inputs
      = f.text_field :url, :required => false, :autofocus => true,  
      placeholder: "the url to the product..."
      %br
      %br
      = f.submit "Add", :class => "btn btn-primary"
  #product_step_2{:style => "display:none;"}


controller:
 @all_the_urls = "list of urls"

 respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :template => 'products/create', :locals =>   
    {:all_image_urls => @all_image_urls}}
  end

 create.js.erb
 $("#product_step_1").hide();
 $("#product_step_2").show();
```

I'm having an issue getting an array of data to display on my bootstrap mult-step modal wizard I'm creating.  The process is, the user first enters a url,  that gets processed by the create action.   After that, I am using a remote form to process via ajax.   The controller action hits the create.js.erb file,  hides the first part of the form, and now displays the next part.

Everything up to the point works fine.  The issue is that on the first part of the form, a variable was set with data(from what the user put in), and now I still need that new data in the part of the form that is no longer hidden, with the show from the jquery.  Although after the controller hit the respond_to, and processes the create.js.erb properly,  the variables are all lost from the controller action.

How can I have this end-to-end so that the variable is passed all the way to the hidden element, so now in the hidden div that is no exposed, that I can see it in the rails view. (which is all the same view).

(I was experimenting with the locals with no luck).

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what you specifically need passed to and from your controllers? e.g. is it the all_image_urls that you need, or the new_product, or the url passed to the new_product form? If you clarified the product objective, not just your code objective, you may get some answers on how to do it, or how to use a different approach. It is unclear as to what you really need.

Comment: Sure, sorry if that's unclear.   So the objective is the user enters a url,  from the url a list of image url's are put together (from nokigiri).   After the url is entered, and the controller action puts together the list of urls available, the next step in the modal should now show a =image_tag of each image to pick from.   My guess is this would iterate over the variable, and each img would have a link_to to a new action to select the final image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand after your latest comment, maybe this will help get you in the right direction. For the url given, I create a Product model, and just generate some random image urls in the model, and then pass the product and those images, back down as json. Then, in the view, I listen for `ajax:success` and handle the images returned as json by generating `img` tags for each one. You could use this example, and wrap each `img` in some other `<a>` tag, with data so that when you click it, you would "choose" that image for the product provided. e.g. `<a href='/product/1/choose_image?image_url=http%3A%2F%2Fplacekitten.com%2F101%2F101'><img></a>`. Then you could store the image url via the controller action, in your ProductController. I'll leave that up to you as to how you'd like to handle that.

Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.create(create_product_params)

    render json: { product: @product, images: @product.fetch_images }
  end

  private 
  def create_product_params
    {}.tap do |h|
      h[:url] = params[:url]
    end
  end
end
```

The view:

```
<h2>Add a new product</h2>

<div id="new-product">
  <%= form_for @product, url: products_url, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.submit("Add") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div id="product-images"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#new-product").on("ajax:success",function(e,data,status,xhr){
    var imageHtml = [],
        i = 0,
        len = data.images.length,
        $imagesArea = $("#product-images");
    $(this).hide();

    for(;i<len;i++){
      imageHtml.push("<img src='")
      imageHtml.push(data.images[i])
      imageHtml.push("' alt='image' /><br/>");
    }
    $imagesArea.html(imageHtml.join(''));
    $imagesArea.show();
  });
</script>
```

The model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :url

  def fetch_images
    images = []

    (100..200).each do |i|
      images.push "http://placekitten.com/#{i}/#{i}"
    end

    images
  end

end
```